# How to call a function inside reduce in Lodash

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I'm trying to get unique value using key from array of object. Everything seems good but function call inside reduce getting `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFile' of undefined`. Is there any possile way to call function inside reduce in TypeScript.

```
_.reduce(items, function(result, value, key) {
    let file = this.getFile(value);
    (result[value] || (result[value] = [])).push(key);
    return result;
}, {});
```

The function which i'm calling inside reduce.

```
async getFile(fileEntry) {
        try {
            return await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
            fileEntry.file(resolve, reject)
            );
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear how you have defined your `getFile` function.

Is it like this

```js
//example 1
async function getFile(fileEntry){
//function body
}
```

or like this

```js
//example 2
this.getFile = async function(fileEntry){
//function body
}
```

If `getFile` function is defined like the *example 1*, then you should call it like this

```js
let file = getFile(value);
```

Hope, this will help you. Thanks!